# using Autohotkey to replace diacritics accents in clipboard

Tags: replace, autohotkey, clipboard, diacritics

I'm trying to write a script in Autohotkey that will take the currently highlighted word, copy it into the clipboard, and then replace accented characters with their non-accented versions. For example, if the word *honorábilem* is in the clipboard, I want to change it to *honorabilem*.

This is what I have tried:

```
F1::
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
clipboard =
Send, ^c 
wordToParse := %clipboard%
wordToParse = RegExReplace(wordToParse,"á","a") ; also tried this: StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, á, a, All
MsgBox, % clipboard
```

But the contents of the clipboard don't change. The *á* never gets replaced with *a*. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the clipboard don't change (after the change from sending <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) becuase you're simply not changing the contents of the clipboard after that.

And another mistake you have is assigning values to variables wrong.
I'd assume you don't know the difference between [`=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetEnv.htm) and [`:=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm).
The difference is that using `=` to assign values is deprecated legacy AHK and should never be used. You're assigning literal text to a variable. As opposed to assigning the result of evaluating some expression, which is what `:=` does.
This line `wordToParse = RegExReplace(wordToParse,"á","a")` assigns literal text to that variable instead of calling the `RegExReplace()` function and assigning its result to the variable.

Also, no reason to regex replace if you're not using regex.
The [`StrReplace()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm) function is what you want.

And then there's also the usage of legacy syntax in an expression:
`wordToParse := %clipboard%`
Referring to a variable by wrapping it in `%` is what you'd do in a legacy syntax.
But since you're not doing that, you're using `:=`, as you should, just ditch the `%`s.

Revised script:

```
F1::
    ;This does nothing for us, removed
    ;SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
    
    ;Empty clipboard
    Clipboard := ""
    
    ;Switched to SendInput, it's documented as faster and more reliable
    SendInput, ^c 
    
    ;Wait for the clipboard to contain something
    ClipWait
    
    wordToParse := Clipboard
    wordToParse := StrReplace(wordToParse, "á", "a")
    
    ;Since you want to display the contents of the clipboard in
    ;a message box, first we need to set what we want into it
    Clipboard := wordToParse
    MsgBox, % Clipboard
return
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and for the explanations about variable assignments and legacy AHK. Very helpful to know. But when running this script on my pc the result still contains the *á* instead of *a*.

Comment: @Ryan It seemed to work for me with no modifications. I highlighted your word above "honorábilem", ran this script, and got "honorabilem" in the message box and clipboard. (I used it to make this comment.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. I'm accepting your answer. There must be some other problem on my end.

Comment: It definitely should work. Don't see how it couldn't work really. Did you figure out what's wrong yet, or not?

Comment: Ah! I think it was because I wasn't saving the .ahk file in UTF-8 with BOM format. It was only in UTF-8. Now it works. Dang encodings.